# Python Flask Postgres error - Can't generate DDL for NullType(); did you forget to specify a type on this Column?

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

Seemingly out of the blue I started getting this error whenever I try to run my flask app.

```
Can't generate DDL for NullType(); did you forget to specify a type on this Column?
```

I've changed nothing with the code or database. It runs fine from another server so I'm thinking it has to be something with the computer I'm running the script on but I'm out of ideas. I restarted my computer, restarted the database. Here is the code

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'postgresql://postgres:password@ngdeva-2/flaskapp2'

db = SQLAlchemy(app)


class Project(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    wmx_jobid = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True, nullable=False)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"{self.id} - {self.wmx_jobid}"


db.create_all()


@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def home():
    message = 'Flask is UP and RUNNING!'
    return jsonify(message)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    from waitress import serve

    serve(app, host="0.0.0.0", port=8080)
```

Answer (score 1):

Something must have been jacked up with my Python venv. I deleted/recreated the venv and that fixed the problem.